# How to define min/max validation on a backbone-form integer text field?

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone-forms

Given the following backbone-forms schema snippet:

```js
number_of_products: {
  type: "Text",
  title: "Number of products",
  validators: ["required", "integer"]
},
```

How would I define validator attributes to restrict input to values between `13` and `42`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with you could change the `type` to `Number` and then add a validation function:

```js
function validateNumber(min, max) {
  return function(val) {
    if (val < min || val > max) {
      return {
        type: 'invalid number',
        message: 'Must be between '+min+' and '+max+'.'
      };
    }
  };
}

...

number_of_products: {
  type: "Number",
  title: "Number of products",
  validators: ["required", validateNumber(13, 42)]
}
```

Comment: Thx! Can I find this somewhere in the documentation? Please add a link if you can name it.

Comment: Do you know if I can limit the number field so that it stops at the limits when the user clicks the arrow-buttons?

Comment: Do you see any chance I can pass `min` and `max` to the function so I can re-use it for other `Number` fields?

Comment: The docs for validation are here: https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#validation

Comment: I've updated the example with something that should work for passing in the min and max values so you can reuse the validator

Answer (score 2):

i think create a validator is more reutilisable :

```
// interval  validator
BackBoneForms.validators.interval = function(options) {
    // get the min value
    var minValue = parseFloat(options.min) || 0;
    var maxValue = parseFloat(options.max) || 0;
    var err = { 
        type: options.type,
        message: "value must between "+minValue+" and "+maxValue
    };
    return function interval(value, attrs) {
        var fieldValue = 0;

        if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') return err;

        // check if the value is number
        if( !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value)) {
            fieldValue = parseFloat(value);
        }
        if(  minValue > fieldValue ||  maxValue < fieldValue  ) {
            return err;
        }
        return ;
    }
}
```

you can use it as :

```
number_of_products: {
  type: "Number",
  title: "Number of products",
 validators: ["required", {
    type : "interval" , 
    max : 10,
    min : 0

 }]
```

}